# Change shape of Polymer element when clicking outside

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have created a custom Polymer element which extends paper-fab. At the moment it is set up so when I click the element, it transforms from a circle to a square. What I am trying to achieve now is when I click outside of the square, it should transform back to a circle.

I am having issues in writing the code to do so. I have looked at core-overlay which dismisses when clicked outside to see if I could use its triggers but I cannot find anything that makes sense.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like paper buttons and paper fabs extend core-focusable, so there's a property "focused" that you can watch for changes. You could have your button be a square while it's focused, and turn back into a circle when it's not.

Files I consulted to track this down:

- https://github.com/Polymer/paper-fab/blob/master/paper-fab.html
- https://github.com/Polymer/paper-button/blob/master/paper-button-base.html
- https://github.com/Polymer/core-focusable/blob/master/core-focusable.js

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!

I extended paper-focusable and made use of the focusAction() function to achieve the desired effect.

Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I extended paper-fab and then used CSS :focus properties to change the shape.

I do have an issue now which I hope that you may know how to address. Within my element, I have other elements. So when the element is a circle you see an icon but when clicked (in focus) it expands to a square and buttons and text input box are visible. Now when these elements are clicked then the square changes back to a circle because it is no longer in focus. 

Do you know how I could keep the circle in focus so its a square whilst interacting with elements within it?

Comment: Good question, I don't have as pithy of an answer for that because it depends on the kind of elements you have inside. For some, you'll need to manually mutate the "focused" property on the fab but for others simply letting the pointer events pass through / bubble up should be enough.

Comment: I see. So my custom element extends paper-fab and within the element I have paper-buttons and a paper-input wrapped in content tags. Are you suggesting that I write some JavaScript that states when say a button is clicked then I call this.focus() because I tried that and it doesn't work properly especially for the input box. If a assign focus to the custom element then you can't type in the input box. Do you have any sample code or guide I could use as a basis? I'm not too familiar with Polymer.

Comment: I'd recommend putting together a jsbin.com example of what you're trying to do and asking it as a new question. I'm having trouble picturing exactly the layout that you're working with here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have asked a new question with a JS Bin showing the code I have written. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028978/how-to-keep-focus-on-custom-polymer-element-when-interacting-with-focusable-elem