# How to keep focus on custom Polymer element when interacting with focusable elements contained within it?

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have created a custom Polymer element which extends paper-fab.

The element contains other elements such as paper-button and paper-input within it. These elements are initially hidden meaning, you just see a FAB.

With the custom element implemented on a different page, when it is clicked it gains focus therefore the custom element changes shape from a circle to a rectangle and shows the paper-button and paper-input elements within it.

When you click away from the custom element such as on a different part of the page, the element changes back to a circle from a rectangle as it no longer has focus. However when interacting with the paper-buttons and paper-input, these elements gain focus and therefore the custom element loses focus and changes shape back to a circle which is not intended here. When interacting with the elements contained within the custom element, the custom element should remain a rectangle; showing and allow interaction with the elements contained within it. When clicking away from the entire custom element, it should change back to a circle and hide the elements within it.

Please see the JS Bin to see how I currently have this set up: http://jsbin.com/wuxuhowavi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Can you edit the jsbin a bit more? As linked it doesn't work at all. I fixed it up a bit (changed the script elements to html imports, instantiated your my-element etc): http://jsbin.com/henaxopejo/1/edit?html,output. The cool part about a jsbin is that we can edit and try it out rather than giving blind advice :]

Comment: I've updated the jsbin, it works correctly now to show you the issue. You have to click the circle for it to become a rectangle and then click within the rectangle to show the content within it. That's not the case in my app as the content just appears when the circle is clicked - not sure why it isn't doing that on jsbin but it doesn't really matter. The jsbin shows the issue; when you click one of the buttons within the rectangle or the text input then focus is lost to "my-element" and it becomes a circle again when it should remain a rectangle. http://jsbin.com/gugisemosi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Have you been able to find a possible solution to this? I am thinking that I am going to have to implement a different approach rather than using focus.